# why the definition of continuity yields zero, but it's used in the derivative definition

Tags: calculus, continuity

i was reading Piskunov's calculus book and he goes to define a criteria for continuity of a function like this:
being
$$
     \Delta y=f(x_{0}+\Delta x)-f(x_{0})
$$
$$
     \lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0} \Delta y=0
$$
and that made me think, why we take this limit to be 0, and then we use the same numerator in the 
differential quoficient, how is then in the second case not zero, or is some detail i am not getting right?
$$
f'(x_{0})=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_{0}+\Delta x)-f(x_{0})}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{0}{\Delta x}??
$$

Comment: What is the limit of $2x/x$ as $x$ goes to $0$? If you aren't sure, plug in some small values of $x$ like $0.001, 0.0001, ...$. Would you agree the limit is $2$ even though the numerator goes to $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement of continuity in your question is actually very intuitive. All $$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} f(x_0+\Delta x) = f(x_0)$$
tells you is that $f(x)$ is defined in a neighborhood of $x_0$ for suitably small values for $\Delta x$ and the value of $f(x)$ is very close to $f(x_0)$ as you approach $x_0$ on the real line by taking $Delta x$ to be smaller and smaller.

Now write down the definition of $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} f(x_0+\Delta x) = f(x_0)$

$$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0: |\Delta x| < \delta \implies |f(x_0+\Delta x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$$

If you take $\Delta x = x-x_0$, you will immediately see that the statement in your question is equal to

$$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0: |x - x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$$

This is indeed the standard definition of continuity in Calculus books. So, both definitions are the same.

As for $f'(x)$, $0/0$ is an indeterminate form. So, you need to resolve it. All formulas for derivatives of functions are proved by resolving the $0/0$ indeterminate form for different functions that arise.

Also, it's a good practice to know why $f'(x)$ is defined like that. It needs to be addressed separately on a different question though.

Comment: there is a typo in your expression $\vert \Delta x \vert < 0 $, it should be $\vert \Delta x \vert < \delta $

Comment: @Zest Thank you for pointing it out. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The last step of your last equation isn't correct: we don't have that $f(x_0 + \Delta x) - f(x_0) = 0$, we have $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} (f(x_0 + \Delta x) - f(x_0)) = 0$.
Maybe what you intended to write was the (extremely tempting!) incorrect equation $$f'(x_0) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+\Delta x) - f(x_0)}{\Delta x} = \frac{\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}(f(x_0 + \Delta x) - f(x_0))}{\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \Delta x} = \frac{0}{0}.$$
But $0/0$ is an indeterminate form, so the fact that we landed on $0/0$ tells us that our use of the limit laws wasn't legitimate (it's a good idea to look back at the hypotheses of this limit law to see why!).

Comment: it was a typo, i added the limit where it belonged

Comment: The issue is still fundamentally the same: In the last equality of the edited version you're taking the limit only of the numerator.  When the denominator doesn't go to 0 to can get the limit of a quotient as the quotient of the limits, but in this case both the numerator and denominator go to 0, so that limit law doesn't apply.

Comment: so i must take the quoficient of both numerator and denominator limits?

Comment: That would be an OK thing to do if the limit of the denominator wasn't also $0$.  The problem is that $0/0$ isn't meaningful, so you can't evaluate this limit that way.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_{0}+\Delta x)-f(x_{0})}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{0}{\Delta x}$$

is not correct. Inside the limit you cannot replace an expression by its limit. Otherwise, you could as well write

$$\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_{0}+\Delta x)-f(x_{0})}{0}$$
or$$\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{0}{0},$$ which don't make sense.

---

In fact, $f(x_{0}+\Delta x)-f(x_{0})$ and $\Delta x$ are both nonzero and decrease *at the same time*, in such a way that their ratio tends to a finite value.

E.g. with $f(x)=x^2$,

$$\frac{(x_0+\Delta x)^2-x_0^2}{\Delta x}=\frac{2x_0\Delta x+\Delta^2x}{\Delta x}=2x_0+\Delta x$$ and not $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try an example.

Suppose $f$ is the function defined by $f(x) = 2x - 1$ for all $x$.
Moreover, suppose that $x_0 = 2.$

Then $f(x_0) = 2(2) - 1 = 3.$

For $\Delta x = 0.1,$ we have $f(x_0+\Delta x) = 2(2 + 0.1) - 1 = 3.2,$ so
$$ \frac{f(x_0+\Delta x)-f(x_0)}{\Delta x} =
\frac{3.2 - 3}{0.1} = \frac{0.2}{0.1} = 2. $$

For $\Delta x = 0.01,$ we have $f(x_0+\Delta x) = 2(2 + 0.01) - 1 = 3.02,$ so
$$ \frac{f(x_0+\Delta x)-f(x_0)}{\Delta x} =
\frac{3.02 - 3}{0.01} = \frac{0.02}{0.01} = 2. $$

Similarly, for $\Delta x = 0.001,$
$$ \frac{f(x_0+\Delta x)-f(x_0)}{\Delta x} =
\frac{3.002 - 3}{0.001} = \frac{0.002}{0.001} = 2; $$

for $\Delta x = 0.0001,$
$$ \frac{f(x_0+\Delta x)-f(x_0)}{\Delta x} =
\frac{3.0002 - 3}{0.0001} = \frac{0.0002}{0.0001} = 2; $$
and so forth.
See a pattern?

The ratio of $f(x_0+\Delta x)$ to $\Delta x$ does not go to zero as $\Delta x$ goes to zero. It never even gets close to zero. It's always $2$, and its limit is $2.$

Now a slightly less simple example:
let $g$ be the function defined by $g(x) = x^2 - 1$,
and again let $x_0 = 2.$ Then $g(x_0) = 2^2 - 1 = 3.$

For $\Delta x = 0.1,$ we have $g(x_0+\Delta x) = (2 + 0.1)^2 - 1 = 3.41,$ so
$$ \frac{g(x_0+\Delta x)-g(x_0)}{\Delta x} =
\frac{3.41 - 3}{0.1} = \frac{0.41}{0.1} = 4.1. $$

For $\Delta x = 0.01,$ we have $g(x_0+\Delta x) = (2 + 0.01)^2 - 1 = 3.0401,$ so
$$ \frac{g(x_0+\Delta x)-g(x_0)}{\Delta x} =
\frac{3.0401 - 3}{0.1} = \frac{0.0401}{0.01} = 4.01. $$

Similarly, for $\Delta x = 0.001,$ 
$$ \frac{g(x_0+\Delta x)-g(x_0)}{\Delta x} =
\frac{3.004001 - 3}{0.1} = \frac{0.004001}{0.001} = 4.001; $$

Similarly, for $\Delta x = 0.0001,$ 
$$ \frac{g(x_0+\Delta x)-g(x_0)}{\Delta x} =
\frac{3.00040001 - 3}{0.1} = \frac{0.00040001}{0.0001} = 4.0001; $$

In fact, the intuition about the limit should be that
$$ \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{g(x_0+\Delta x)-g(x_0)}{\Delta x} = 4, $$
because that's where the sequence $4.1, 4.01, 4.001, 4.0001$ is heading.

But in order to make this really *mathematics,* rather than just a few examples followed by a guess, we need to develop a more rigorous definition of the limit 
(which I hope your instructor or textbook has shown you)
so that we can say more than just it *looks like* the limit is $4$ in this case;
we should be able to *prove* that the ratio 
$\frac{g(x_0+\Delta x)-g(x_0)}{\Delta x}$
goes to $4$ as $\Delta x$ goes to zero.
In order to be sure that the mathematics is correct and there is no funny business about the function $g$ that would throw legitimate doubt on whether
$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}  \frac{g(x_0+\Delta x)-g(x_0)}{\Delta x},$
we need such a rigorous definition of a limit,
because some other functions *do* have some funny business that *does* throw legitimate doubt on whether such a limit exists for those functions at certain values of $x_0,$ and we have to conclude that the limit does not exists and those functions do not have derivatives in those cases.

---

So the answer to why we can't just say
$$
\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+\Delta x)-f(x_0)}{\Delta x}
\stackrel?=\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac0{\Delta x}
$$
is that **that's not how the limit works.**
If you let $\Delta x = 0,$ then the ratio 
$\frac{f(x_0+\Delta x)-f(x_0)}{\Delta x}$ is not a number;
but if $\Delta x$ is anything else then the ratio is a number,
and could be any number depending on exactly which function $f$ is defined to be.

Sometimes, indeed,  that number goes to zero as $\Delta x$ goes to zero
(in which case we conclude that $f'(x_0) = 0$), 
but more typically the ratio does something else.
Sometimes it goes to some other particular limit value, 
which we then say is $f'(x_0).$
Sometimes it grows without limit, or it bounces around and never settles on any one value as $\Delta x$ goes to zero, and then we have to say that the derivative of $f$ does not exist at $x_0,$ that is, $f'(x_0)$ does not exist.